# Error: String types not allowed (at 'ga_logLevel' with value 'verbose')

Tags: android, google-analytics

According to [Google Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration#ez2). the line below must be added, but eclipse wouldn't compile because 'verbose' isn't a bool

```
<bool name="ga_logLevel">verbose</bool>
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">XXXXXX</string>

    <!-- Enable Activity tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <!-- <bool name="ga_debug">false</bool> -->
    <bool name="ga_logLevel">verbose</bool>

</resources>
```

Comment: what happens if you change the ga_logLevel to a `string` resource instead of `bool`. this probably is documented incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You must declare ga_logLevel as string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">XXXXXX</string>

    <!-- Enable Activity tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <!-- <bool name="ga_debug">false</bool> -->
    <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>

</resources>
```